# Possible argument injection bypass in bash via php script

Tags: php, bash, shell, terminal, sh

i'm developing some script for a project and i came accross a dilemma i'm not very sure about.

Essentially i have a php script that parses user input coming from a control panel.

what the user can control is actually the argument of the binary that is getting executed through shell_exec. E.g.

> /bin/mybinary usercontrolled_argument

To avoid the possibility of letting the user chaining other commands i'm using this:

```
$paramString = "'".str_replace("'", "'\\''", $paramString)."'";
```

in this way the argument passed to the shell is gonna finish between single quotes like that:

> /bin/mybinary 'usercontrolled_argument'

and just to be safe i've also added the following to block some chars:

```
$paramString = str_replace("%", "%25", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace("+", "%2b", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace(" ", "%20", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace("'", "%27", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace('"', "%22", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace('`', "%60", $paramString);
$paramString = str_replace('*', "%2a", $paramString);
```

what i forgot to mention is that i am iterating through arguments which could be multiple (if the user sends more than one) so it would be like:

> /bin/mybinary 'usercontrolled_arg1' 'usercontrolled_arg2'

what i am asking is, is there any chance the user can execute somehow any malicious command ?

thank you !

P.s : "escapeshellarg" does not work, because it strippes UTF8 characters from string and setlocale does not help

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg

Comment: Since you are using single quotes already, the only characters you would have to be aware of, are other single quotes, or backslashes. However I wonder why you need an interim shell at all, to run your binary? If you know where the binary is located, and you have all the parameters, what is the shell used for?

Comment: Actually, only the single quote is problematic in this scenario; backslash, too, is simply literal inside double quotes.

Comment: But a more common and secure solution is to enumerate the values you want to permit, and escape or reject everything else.